# Access ios apps documents and other files

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a doubt if any one can access the files and document directories of an iphone app. Need to check if anyone can access the files if they get the device. I have a sqlite file in my app whose data is sensitive i dont want other users to hack or access it. 
Please let me know how we can access any apps database.

Comment: Anyone with access to the device can easily access the app and any of its sandbox files unless the device is passcode protected and locked.

Comment: Hi thats ok but how will they do it, will they use xcode, itunes or is there any other way or software to do that.

Comment: You need to encrypt the sqlite database. Look into SQLCipher or [SEE](https://www.sqlite.org/see).

Comment: There are several application for the Mac and Windows that can access the user's data if the iOS device either has no passcode entered or it is the device owner. Examples include iExplorer and iBrowse, .

Comment: thanks @rmaddy i am considering to use SQLCipher..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the user, basically, if the user has set a passcode, it will encrypt all data on the device. If the user has not set a passcode, then data will live unencrypted. As a rule of thumb, you must assume if the information lives on the device, that information might be at risk.

Here is what apple has to say about it:

> Data protection is available for devices that offer hardware
>   encryption, including iPhone 3GS and later, all iPad models, and iPod
>   touch (3rd generation and later). Data protection enhances the
>   built-in hardware encryption by protecting the hardware encryption
>   keys with your passcode. This provides an additional layer of
>   protection for your email messages attachments, and third-party
>   applications.][1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202064)

Also:

> On devices running iOS 8, your personal data such as photos, messages
>   (including attachments), email, contacts, call history, iTunes
>   content, notes, and reminders is placed under the protection of your
>   passcode.